# Implicit creation of helpers - routes.rb and 'match' statements

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am reading Obie Fernandez' "The Rails 3 Way", and there is a bit of it that I am not sure I understand correctly. I am new to rails, and want to make sure I understand it correctly. I have some experience with vanilla Ruby. Not much, but some.

The text in question is as follows: (regarding routing and the config/routes.rb file)

"...

By creating a route like

```
match 'auctions/:id' => "auction#show", :as => 'auction'
```

you gain the ability to use nice helper methods in situations like

```
link_to item.description, auction_path(item.auction)
```

..."

My question is, specifically what part of `match 'auctions/:id' => "auction#show", :as => 'auction'` creates the helper functions? (such as `link_to auction` and `auction_path()` ) Is it the `:as => 'auction'` part? Would any helpers be created without appending `:as => 'auction'`?

My confusion stems from other guides I have seen where this is omitted, and yet helpers seem to be created regardless. What specifically does rails use in `match` statements in the routes.rb file to create helpers? If it isn't the `:as => 'auction'` part, then what is the specific purpose of appending this to the `match` statement?

I know this seems like a super basic question, but this detail seems to get glossed over in the texts I have read thus far. Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the `:as => 'named_route'` part that creates the named route (which in turn creates the helpers). As for leaving it off, are you referring to instances of `resources :something` in `routes.rb`? The `resources` method generates a set of URL helpers based on the name of the resource automagically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm referring to other peoples' code I have read on github to try to familiarize myself with how rails works, and my own fumbling around with rails to date. (I have about a week's experience with rails, and about 6 month's experience with ruby.) I'm beginning to get the feeling that I'd have been better off not knowing any ruby at all going into this. This sheds a lot of light into problems I've been experiencing so far with helpers. I'd upding your answer if I had a little more reputation. Thanks again!

Comment: There was a threshold of knowledge (at least for me) where Rails stopped being so "magical" and started making sense. The Rails code can be a little overwhelming but reading it is a great way to see how things work. I think in the end you'll be better off for knowing Ruby before you started learning Rails.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried this:

```
match "alfa/beta", to: 'users#new'
```

In this case, even without an `:as => 'named_route'`, I got for free the following helper

```
alfa_beta_path
```

which, as expected, points to `users#new`.
So, it seems that helpers are also automagically generated by parsing the route's string, in case there is no `:as` specification.